# Why don't my Android BroadcastReceiver messages arrive?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-service

This is yet another question about why a `BroadcastReceiver` doesn't see the messages being sent to it. I've looked at a dozen examples and other questions their solutions seem the same as mine but mine doesn't work.

My receiver is in a service. Here's the manifest fragment:

```xml
<service android:name="com.madurasoftware.vmnotifications.services.BLEService"
    android:label="BluetoothService"
    android:process="com.madurasoftware.vmnotifications.services.VMServices">
</service>
```

The service registers the receiver like this:

```kotlin
    private val messageReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onReceive() called")
            val message = intent.getStringExtra(BluetoothService.MESSAGE)
            NotificationQueue.add(message)
        }
    }
    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate() called")
        val filter = IntentFilter()
        filter.addAction(BluetoothService.MESSAGE_ACTION)
        baseContext.registerReceiver(this.messageReceiver, filter )
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        baseContext.unregisterReceiver(this.messageReceiver)
    }
```

Because I am dynamically registering the receiver I don't add anything about it to the manifest.
I send from a button in my `MainActivity` like this:

```kotlin
            Intent().also { intent ->
                intent.setAction(BluetoothService.MESSAGE_ACTION)
                intent.putExtra(BluetoothService.MESSAGE, "xyz")
                sendBroadcast(intent)
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "sendBroadcast() called")
```

When I press the button I see that the logged `sendBroadcast()` message shows up, but the `onReceive()` log message does not. So it isn't being delivered.
Can anyone see why?
I'm using API 29 and this is my full manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.madurasoftware.vmnotifications">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-feature
            android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le"
            android:required="true" />

    <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
            android:fullBackupContent="@xml/my_backup_rules">

        <activity android:name=".ui.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name="com.madurasoftware.vmnotifications.services.NotificationService"
                 android:label="@string/app_name"
                 android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service android:name="com.madurasoftware.vmnotifications.services.BLEService"
                 android:label="BluetoothService"
                 android:process="com.madurasoftware.vmnotifications.services.VMServices">
        </service>

        <service android:name="com.madurasoftware.vmnotifications.services.BluetoothService"
                 android:label="BluetoothService"
                 android:process="com.madurasoftware.vmnotifications.services.VMServices">
        </service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: Try to make broadcast more explicit by adding `intent.setPackage(getPackageName())`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I added `                intent.setPackage("com.madurasoftware.vmnotifications.services")
` to the intent and retried. No difference. The broadcaster is in a different package from the receiver so I used the receiver's package name.